# How do I remove a Facebook app request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Unfortunately, because of some fat fingering when browsing the Klout website from my iPad I accidentally sent app requests to 50 friends. I am really annoyed by these sort of requests and certainly did not intend to send them to my friends.

- Can I view the app requests I've sent on Facebook?
- Can I undo the requests that I've sent?
- Can I add a privacy setting to prevent any Facebook app (Klout or otherwise) from ever sending these requests in the future?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a native way with Klout's UI that I am aware of. Your best bet is finding a Chrome Extension that handles Facebook JS SDK API calls, then you can do something like this

```
FB.api('/me/apprequests', function(response) {
  var ids = [];
  for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
    FB.api('/' + response.data[i].id, 'DELETE', 
      function(response){ console.log('cleared request:' + response) } 
    );
    console.log('For: ' + response.data[i].to.name);
  }
});
```

Quick and dirty would be to just paste this into your Developer console on Klout's page.

[image: Klout page with console]

Comment: This will show every request sent? Or just those that were answered?

Comment: @ahsteele every request sent that hasn't been handled (via deletion) in Klout and still exists as a request in App Center on the receiver's end